# How to test cached response in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, urlsession

I'm trying to write unit tests for my `URLSession` caching in swift.

Is there a way to know if the response came from the server or from the cache, so I can write unit tests that check if my responses are being cached?

Comment: Not sure _why_ you want to do this. I can imagine that you want to test your own network library, where this may make sense. If you want to test an API though, URLCaching is an underlying detail that IMHO should not be tested in an API test. Also, whether a response will be cached or not also depends on the response and the Cache-Control response header - which is determined by the backend and usually also not testable in a Unit Test (possibly with an Integration test), but this is better done in tests on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to subclass URLCache to create a *mock* and configure your URLSession so that it uses your MockURLCache.

Your MockURLCache overrides:

```
override func getCachedResponse(for dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, completionHandler: @escaping (CachedURLResponse?) -> Void) {
    super.getCachedResponse(for: dataTask) { cachedURLResponse in
        self.retrievedCachedResponse?(cachedURLResponse) 
        completionHandler(cachedURLResponse)
    }
}
```

where `self.retrievedCachedResponse(_:)` is an optional of type closure:

```
class MockURLCache: URLCache {
    var retrievedCachedResponse: ((CachedURLResponse?) -> Void)?
    ...
}
```

which you can conveniently set in a unit test. This closure may then fulfil a XCTestExpectation which you can assert.